# How do I load an .xml file from disk as an element tree using lxml?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I have a series of XML files on my drive that I want to do the following to:

- Load into lxml as element tree and parse with xpath
- Load another XML file as element tree and parse with xpath to find correct location to append information to
- The information I am parsing from the series of XML files should be set to variables so I can run some logic on the results before appending back to the big .xml file

I'm having some trouble with file types / loading the XML files properly as an element tree so they can be acted upon by lxml. I've tried it a few different ways but keep running into various problems. The current problem reads:

> TypeError: Argument '_parent' has incorrect type (expected
>   lxml.etree._Element, got list)

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
import requests

file = 'bgg.xml'
# parse the xml file from disk as an element tree in lxml?
treebgg = etree.parse(file)

# create a list of IDs to iterate through from the bgg.xml file
gameList = treebgg.xpath("//root/BGG/@ID")

# iterate through the IDs
for x in reversed(gameList):
    url = 'https://somewhere.com/xmlapi/' + str(x)
    page = requests.get(url)
    # pull an xml file from a web url and turn it into an element tree in lxml
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    # set my root variable so I can append children to this location
    root = tree.xpath("//root/BGG[@ID=x]")
    name = tree.xpath("//somewhere/name[@primary='true']"
    # append child info into bgg.xml
    child = etree.SubElement(root, "Name")
    child.text = name

# write bgg.xml back to file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the root of the `bgg.xml` tree:

```
rootbgg = treebgg.getroot()
```

And use it to append children to:

```
child = etree.SubElement(rootbgg, "Name")
```

---

> I'm having another problem...how do I select the correct element? I don't want to append to the root of the xml file itself.

You now would need to redesign the way you iterate over elements:

```
gameList = treebgg.xpath("//root/BGG")

# iterate through the IDs
for game in reversed(gameList):
    url = 'https://somewhere.com/xmlapi/' + game.attrib["id"]
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    # TODO: get the name

    # append child info into bgg.xml
    child = etree.SubElement(game, "Name")
    child.text = name
```

Comment: I tried rootbgg = treebgg.getroot() but I'm having another problem...how do I select the correct element? I don't want to append to the root of the xml file itself.

    <root>
        <BGG ID="123">
            <Something>Hi</Something>
            #append here
        <BGG ID="234">
        <BGG ID="345">
    </root>

Comment: @Aro updated with a sample code to proceed. I hope I understand what are you trying to do correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem.